# determine if you have a 64bit processor

Tags: kernel, 64-bit, 32-bit

I would like to find out on the console if my processor is 64 bit capable.

I can find out that I have installed the 32 bit version of Ubuntu with

```
uname -a
```

If it doesn't contain `64` at all, then I know I have a 32 bit kernel.

But how can I find out if I could install the 64 bit version as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either run

```
lscpu
```

or

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

The most definative way would probably be to run:

```
lscpu | grep op-mode
```

That will give you a nice 1 line return.